# Service Order Line Note not printing on Invoice

Tags: acumatica

I am creating an Invoice from Service Order but, the Note created in the Line Order, is not showing on the Invoice.
When I create an Invoice from a Sales Order, the Line Note shows on the Invoice.
Am I missing some management feature that I should turn on?
Any Help will be appreciated.

Alfredo

Answer (score 0):

Copy line notes to Shipments and Invoices is depended on settings at Order Type level. See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: John, 
I forgot to mention that my setting in the Order Type screen, it is like the one you have on the screenshot. That is why I don't understand, why it is not printing for the Services Order but it does for the Sales Order.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess here but might be worth to also take a look at the Service Order Types configuration page too. It has a section about Invoice Generation Settings where you can specify to generate the invoice from the sales order. Since the copy line settings apply to Sales Order Type SO I thought there might be a link there.

Comment: John thanks for your help.
The issue was solved in 2018 R2.

Comment: thanks for the update Alfredo, is this based on the configuration settings or issue related to service in the old version.

Comment: John,
In the new Service Order Type there are a bunch of new options to set and there, is the new option "Copy Line Notes To Invoice".  
I have tried to posted the answer to my question, with a screenshot showing how the new screen looks like but, for some reason it does not work.